# Flutter does it possible to make IOS search bar ui ? and how?

Tags: flutter, uisearchbar, ios-ui-automation

I am want to make an IOS ui of a search bar but all I have found is regular ui's
if someone know how can I do that it will be great

example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter cupertino library and make the same Swiftful IOS styled search UI in flutter check this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSearchTextField-class.html) for more info

below is the code on how you can use it in your app,

```
class MyPrefilledSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPrefilledSearch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPrefilledSearch> createState() => _MyPrefilledSearchState();
}

class _MyPrefilledSearchState extends State<MyPrefilledSearch> {
  late TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: 'initial text');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSearchTextField(controller: _textController);
  }
}
```

then use it like this

```
class MyPrefilledSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPrefilledSearch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPrefilledSearch> createState() => _MyPrefilledSearchState();
}

class _MyPrefilledSearchState extends State<MyPrefilledSearch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSearchTextField(
      onChanged: (String value) {
        print('The text has changed to: $value');
      },
      onSubmitted: (String value) {
        print('Submitted text: $value');
      },
    );
  }
}
```